# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'dislike_count'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\Desktop\Computer Files\SenMusic\senmusic.py", line 61, in play
    await player.queue(url, search=True)
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\DiscordUtils\Music.py", line 190, in queue
    song = await get_video_data(url, search, bettersearch, self.loop)
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\DiscordUtils\Music.py", line 92, in get_video_data
    dislikes = data["dislike_count"]
KeyError: 'dislike_count'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rcesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'dislike_count'
```

So i think we have all heard that youtube decided to get rid of the dislike counter. I think this new update may have ruined my private music bot since it takes the youtube videos to play music.

I was wondering if any of you had a fix for this, since its a new problem I don't know if it can be fixed yet. If its possible that any of you can't fix my problem and know of an alternative to youtube using python for playing music please let me know the python library of it to be able to add it to my private music bot Thanks!
I'll leave the bot code down here:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import nacl
import DiscordUtils
import random
import asyncio


sm = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "sm ", help_command=None, intents = discord.Intents().all())
music = DiscordUtils.Music()

@sm.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(sm))
    await sm.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Music 24/7 | sm help"))

@sm.command()
async def join(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    if voicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! You are not in a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

@sm.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    mevoicetrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if voicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! You are not in a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    if mevoicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! I am not connected to a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

    if ctx.message.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        await server.disconnect()

        player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
        player.disable()

@sm.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)

    if not player:
        player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)

    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await player.queue(url, search=True)
        song = await player.play()
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":arrow_forward: | Playing {song.name}", value="-----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
        song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song.name} has been added to the queue!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def queue(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f"{', '.join([song.name for song in player.current_queue()])}", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.pause()
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":pause_button: | {song.name} has been stopped!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.resume()
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":arrow_forward: | Resuming {song.name}!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.toggle_song_loop()
    if song.is_looping:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":repeat: | {song.name} is now looping!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":no_entry_sign: | Error! {song.name} is not looping!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def np(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":arrow_forward: | {player.now_playing().name} is currently playing!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def remove(ctx, index):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.remove_from_queue(int(index))
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song.name} has been removed from queue!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.skip(force=True)
    if len(song) == 2:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song[0].name} has been skipped to {song[1].name}!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song.name} has been skipped!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

 #help command

@sm.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name="Command List", icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm join**", value="Joins the voice channel (Required for playing music)", inline=True)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm play**", value="Searches for a song name or plays a youtube link", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm stop**", value="Stops a song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm resume**", value="Resumes a song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm skip**", value="Skips the current song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm queue**", value="Shows the songs in queue", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm remove**", value="Removes a song from queue", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm np**", value="Shows the now playing song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm loop**", value="Loops the current song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm leave**", value="Leaves the voice channel", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

sm.run(token)
```

Comment: You can use youtube_dl library (https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/)

Answer (score 1):

this happens because Google has removed the disliked response from the API, hence when the code is trying to access a dictionary attribute with no key throws the error.
To Fix this simply comment on the lines, accessing ['dislike_count'].

[comment in the file music.py in DiscordUtils package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJgyF.png)

Note:- DiscordUtils package can be found in "virtual_env_name/lib/python3.x/site-packages/DiscordUtils" if using an virtual enviroment.
OR
the path where you have installed python3.

[See line no 56.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaxoo.png)
[line no 72.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jFHE.png)

[and line no 92.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJDV.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is not a good idea to send images of code. It could be better to include the necessary snippets as text in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem do this :
in this location C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pafy in this file backend_youtube_dl.py find this line of code and remove it:
`self._dislikes = self._ydl_info['dislike_count']`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30848548)